# Power supply rate for Riger ADSL Modem 2/2+ DB102

Tags: power-supply, modem, adapter, ac-adapter

Does anyone know what type of power adapter for this kind of modem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the manual indicates it is a 5.2V 1A converter.
https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://site.riger.com.my/Clients/riger/db102.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwierdWyzL3MAhVptYMKHaCNCHAQFggfMAE&usg=AFQjCNGItxd4vQL3vN-OLemH4qwyjRvNsw&sig2=iHWVZuE1z7Gb4CfIDly2lQ